# How to add recently installed python as the base interpreter for virtualenv in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I installed Python 3.10 using brew and its not being shown in the list of base interpreters for venv when I create a new project in PyCharm. I have both 3.9 and 3.10 and I want both to be listed here. Can it be done? If so, how?

[image: New Project]

Comment: Have you tried clicking the `...` and navigating to the install directory?

Comment: Yeah I can do that. But everytime I have to do that. It doesn't come automatically like all the other ones.

Comment: I am also really annoyed with this and would love to find how to fix this for good